# How to simplify into sum notation in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Is it possible somehow to simplify a sympy expression into sum notation?

For example, with

```py
from sympy import *

init_printing()
x, n = symbols('x n')
expr = x + x**2 + x**3 + x**4 + x**5
```

I get in IPython console:

```py
In [3]: expr
Out[3]:
 5    4    3    2
x  + x  + x  + x  + x
```

Now, trying to naively simplify it will produce just:

```py
In [4]: simplify(expr)
Out[4]:
  ⎛ 4    3    2        ⎞
x⋅⎝x  + x  + x  + x + 1⎠
```

What I would like to see is something like:

```py
In [5]: Sum(x**n, (n, 1, 5))
Out[5]:
  5
 ___
 ╲
  ╲    n
  ╱   x
 ╱
 ‾‾‾
n = 1
```

Is this somehow possible in sympy?

Comment: I don't think anything ready made exists for this but you might be able to make something like that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see anything to do this in sympy module directly, but I see the `<sympy.simplify.simplify>` class has a `sum_combine` function that try combine a summation list into one summation. Then I did this:

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy.simplify.simplify import sum_combine
init_printing()
x, n = symbols('x n')
expr = x + x**2 + x**3 + x**4 + x**5


def get_sum_terms(expr):
    new_terms = []
    for term in expr.args:
        if isinstance(term, sympy.core.power.Pow):
            base = term.base
            exp = term.exp
            new_term = Sum(base**n, (n, exp, exp))
            new_terms.append(new_term)
        else:
            new_terms.append(Sum(term**n, (n, 1, 1)))
    return new_terms

def simplify_to_sum(expr):
    sums = []
    for term in get_sum_terms(expr):
        sums.append(term)
    return sum_combine(sums)


pprint(simplify_to_sum(expr))
```

Out:

```
  5
 ___
 ╲
  ╲    n
  ╱   x
 ╱
 ‾‾‾
n = 1
```

Maybe you still need verify if the return of `simplify_to_sum` is better than the original expression, I dont test enough, but it works fine. All times `simplify_to_sum` is not better, just use `simplify` in this and get a better expression.